# Crystal Reports: previewing page breaks

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Is there a way in Crystal Reports 2008 to have a preview of page breaks while in design mode ?
I'd like to have a visual clue of when the page breaks while I'm designing a report, without
having to jump to the preview pane every now and then to check how it looks like...
Does that function even exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CR2008, but intuitively I doubt it.

You could turn on every single "New Page Before" option in your Section Expert.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing.  It's my 1st time with CR and while it seems very powerful, I find it very user unfriendly :/

Comment: I feel the same way with most software in the beginning.  After you use it for a few months, it'll make much more sense to you.